# How to make an executable?

Tags: interoperability

I made a program  in mathematica and I want to know if Mathematica permits to generate an executable code (*.exe) for running it on a machine where Mathematica is not installed. This is my program:

```
datos2 = Import["d2.txt", "Data"];

f = Flatten[Position[datos2, {0, 0, 0, 0}]];
p = Insert[Insert[f, 0, 1], Length[datos2] + 1, -1];

j = Table[0, {i, Length[p] - 1}];

Table[j[[i]] = Table[{datos2[[q, 1]], datos2[[q, 2]]}, {q, p[[i]] + 1, p[[i + 1]] - 1}],
                 {i, Length[p] - 1}];
m = Table[{Line[j[[i]]]}, {i, Length[p] - 1}];
i = Table[0, {m, Length[p] - 1}}];

Do[i[[t]] = ParallelTable[RegionIntersection[m[[t]], m[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[p] - 1}, 
  Method -> Automatic]; i[[t, t]] = EmptyRegion[2];, {t, 1, Length[p] - 1}]

Do[Print[i[[u]]], {u, Length[i]}]
```

Comment: https://www.wolfram.com/engine/

Comment: You cannot run Wolfram Language code on a machine where some Wolfram Language kernel (such as Wolfram Engine) is not installed

Answer (score 1):

You can save it as a CDF file.

Users can download the CDFPlayer by going to the link:

http://www.wolfram.com/player/

CDF doesn't support everything but handles `Manipulate` which is very valueable.

It can be used to play the interactive demonatrations located at

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/

Comment: If `Import` is part of the final goal then OP has a problem.

Comment: datos2 is  an input  file in the executable